# How can I use polymer as file:// based static sdk?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have tried to build an app using polymer-cli, and let that package all the required files, but I am not sure if this is doing what I want, because the build code doesn't match the examples I have seen where you request  and webcomponents-loader.js. My build doesn't make a webcomponents-loader.

I know it is possible to create an SDK, because the code works on sites like codepen and js fiddle.

I just want a drop-in solution to start creating components using polymer, and it must be able to work from file:// urls.

I have a custom application which gets all its content from file urls and has no webserver to speak of.

I have not seen any information or tutorials which meet my specification.

Comment: [this is one reason why i think node projects are crap for creating javascript components]; I don't comprehend all of this node/bower/yarn stuff. People are doing too much with it. Like this polymer project. They have taken it upon themselves to create a whole webserver based sdk with tools and stuff, but the whole project, from my perspective, is just the javascript code and resource files needed to make webbrowsers do their thing.

Comment: ^ it really is ridiculous. The whole build process could be replaced by a single web-archiving application with some built in code munging. I miss the days when people kept things simple. Now its like they do overly complicated things to keep themselves busy.